# How does r evaluate many Boolean disjunctions?

Tags: r, time

Consider the following pseudo r code where I define two Boolean expressions. Note that the second is a trivial disjunction of the first 6 times.

```
testCondition1 <- function(testObject){tc(testObject)}

testCondition6 <- function(testObject){tc(testObject)|tc(testObject)|tc(testObject)|tc(testObject)|tc(testObject)|tc(testObject)}
```

Now I want to test how long it takes to evaluate these expressions for an object that makes them both true. So I did something like this:

```
start.time <- Sys.time()

if (testCondition1(satisfyingObject)) {
print("end")
}

end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
print(time.taken)
```

whereby the second time I replaced the expression accordingly.

With `testCondition1` it takes about 12 seconds to evaluate as true and prints "end" accordingly. When I test this with `testCondition6` it takes about 40 seconds. Why should this be so? Does r evaluate every part of the Boolean expression? Is there a better way to speed this up?

Comment: try using `||` instead of `|`; the former does short-circuiting.

Comment: @BenBolker That indeed seems to work. In fact, it tests at 6 seconds, so faster than the original test!(?)

Comment: I think you'll find that if you test with an object that makes them both *false*, your run times will be higher, indicating that the short-circuiting tried all possibles before terminating as `FALSE`.

Comment: that's probably just random variation in testing.  Try `rbenchmark::benchmark` or `microbenchmark::microbenchmark` for more precision